Error compiling with NewDocumentCommand
I am not able to compile the following document with pdflatex.
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{graphicx}    
    
\NewDocumentCommand{\logoscale}{}{0.3}    
%\newcommand{\logoscale}{0.3}  <---- works with this  
    
\NewDocumentCommand{\mylogo}{}%    
  {\includegraphics[scale=\logoscale]{example-image-a}}                                                                         
                                                                                                                                
\begin{document}                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                
\mylogo                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy                                                        
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam                                                        
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet                                                         
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit                                                         
amet.                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                
\end{document}

On compiling, I get the following error:
./x.tex:21: pdfTeX error (\pdfsetmatrix): Unrecognized format..
<argument> ...shipout:D \box_use:N \l_shipout_box 
                                                  \__shipout_drop_firstpage_...
l.21 \end{document}

The same document compiles if I use newcommand. I need some help in understanding where the problem is.

Try with \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\logoscale}{}{0.3}

Just for holding a value, there is no real reason to use the \New...  macros.

Like @daleif says, for macros holding just a value stick to \newcommand.

\def\logoscale{0.3} will be without problems. LaTeX introduces tons of alternatives of \def primitive and this causes problems like this.

@wipet Indeed I prefer \def myself because it is the simplest solution. However, it is not without problems, the biggest one is that you can easily overwrite an earlier defined macro unintentionally because (La)TeX doesn't warn about redefinitions with \def.

Thanks for the clarifications. If someone makes an answer, I can accept it.

@daleif I agree that just holding a value is not useful in this case. As the macro is used in many places, changing the scale uniformly via a macro would be easier. Are there alternatives for just holding a value?

@mas the point is not to not use a macro, but that there is no reason to use \New... to define it. just use \newcommand.... (\def is OK only if you are certain you won't overwrite anything, though \newcommand\mymacro{}\def\mymacro{...} is fine. in terms of the \NewDocument.../\NewExpandable... etc., it is not clear how this kind of case should be handled at the document level. at the package/class level, it is clear, but at the document level the older interfaces are probably as good as anything. (imho)

Thanks for the clarification. I am trying to learn the new way of defining macros (I know that newcommand is not going away).

This question is similar to: Using command defined with \NewDocumentCommand in TikZ. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. It may seem that the similar question is completely different because it is about TikZ instead of \includegraphics. However, the expansion problem and its solution are actually the same.

@cabohah I see how the solution is the same, but I'm curious how the expansion problem is the same.  In the other question, the problem essentially comes down to "pgf is doing its own parsing and expansion separate from TeX".  That doesn't seem to be the case here (at least to my eyes).  How is expansion a problem?

@Teepeemm Depending on the context graphicx uses \edef internally when processing scale. And there \logoscale is not expanded, because \NewDocumentCommand defines it protected. And in another context, graphicx uses the argument of scale as a prefix factor to a length. This also needs an expandable macro. So expansion is the problem.
